# vim : Find a pattern, skip a word and append something in all matching lines

Tags: regex, vim, pattern-matching

I am aware of the simple search and replace commands `(:%s/apple/orange/g)` in vim where we find all 'apples' and replace them with 'orange'.

But is it possible to do something like this in vim? 
Find all 'Wheat' in a file and append "store" after skipping the next word (if any)?

Example:
Original file contents :

```
Wheat flour
Wheat bread
Rice flour
Wheat
```

After search and replace:

```
Wheat flour store
Wheat bread store
Rice flour
Wheat store
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the perfect time to use the `global` command. It will apply a command to every line that matches a given regex.

```
                        *:g* *:global* *E147* *E148*
:[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd]
            Execute the Ex command [cmd] (default ":p") on the
            lines within [range] where {pattern} matches.
```

In this case, the command is `norm A store` and the regex is `wheat`. So putting it all together, we have

```
:g/Wheat/norm A store
```

Now, you *could* do this with the substitute command, but I find global is a lot more convenient and readable. In this case, you'd have:

```
:%s/Wheat.*/& store
```

Which means:

```
:%s/                " On every line, replace...
    Wheat           "   Wheat
         .*         "   Followed by anything
           /        " with...
            &       "   The entire line we matched
              store "   Followed by 'store'
```